# Databricks how to exit the entire 'job' in the notebooks orchestration workflow?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Say I have a simple notebook orchestration :

```
Notebook A -> Notebook B
```

`Notebook A` finish first then trigger `Notebook B`

I am wondering if there is an out of box method to allow `Notebook A` to terminate the entire job? (without running `Notebook B`).

Putting `dbutils.notebook.exit` in `Notebook A`  will exit `Notebook A` but `Notebook B` still can run.

P.S.
Passing parameters between `Notebooks` to terminate all the down stream`Notebooks` one-by-one is an alternative solution but not ideal.
I want a solution to kill the job at the ***root*** `Notebook`.
And, I do not want to `raise Exceptions` in `Notebook A`and kill the job by running into an "error" status.

Comment: It might not be possible to stop the job without raising Exceptions in Databricks workflows. But you can use Data factory with the help of `dbutils.notebook.exit` to execute Notebook, B if condition satisfies. I can provide a solution for that if necessary.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Thank you very much for your reply but I am still looking for a solution within Databricks.

Comment: You can now pass parameters between tasks.

https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/share-task-context.html

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no way to stop the present cell after a successful run in "run all" scenario.
Additionally, you can always put an error in the cell where you want run all to stop since errors stop "run all".
Also, you can run all cells above and run all cells below. For example: If you want to run all cells up to cell X, go to cell X+1 and “run all cells above”.

Comment: Hi - What I am asking has nothing to do with the "Run All" command within a single Notebook.